# Using a define (or a class constant) to call a variable method?

Tags: php, variables, methods, call

Is it possible to :

```
define('DEFAULT_METHOD', 'defaultMethod');

class Foo
{
    public function defaultMethod() { }
}

$foo = new Foo();
$foo->DEFAULT_METHOD();
```

Or do I have to :

```
$method = DEFAULT_METHOD;
$foo->$method();
```

And what about a class constant instead of a define ?

Comment: why constants? isn't it easier to just `$foo->defaultMethod()`?

Comment: I need to do that for something and i'm not sure people will want me to paste my whole code and explain the whole story so i just kept the minimum required to explain what i need to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use a variable or constant as the method name, you have to put it into curly brackets:

```
$foo->{DEFAULT_METHOD}();
```

The same technique works for variables, including static class attributes:

```
class Foo {
    public static $DEFAULT_METHOD = 'defaultMethod';
    public function defaultMethod() { echo "Cool!\n"; }
}

$foo = new Foo();
$foo->{FOO::$DEFAULT_METHOD}();
```

In fact, practically any expression that results in a valid method name could be used:

```
$foo->{'default'.'Method'}();
```

Comment: Thanks ! Didn't know this. Might be handy some day :)
`EDIT` : By class constants i meant : `class Foo { const BAR = 'Baz'; }`

Comment: Great explanation! This looks like a winner :)

Answer (score 2):

You could set it to a variable first as in your example :)

Example: http://codepad.org/69W4dYP1

```
<?php
  define('DEFAULT_METHOD', 'defaultMethod');

  class Foo {
      public function defaultMethod() { echo 'yay!'; }
  }

  $foo = new Foo();
  $method = DEFAULT_METHOD;
  $foo->$method();
?>
```